# Add select quantity options on product page Magento 2

Tags: product, magento-2.1, quantity

I want to change quantity textbox to quantity dropdown on product page. I found solutions that work for magento 1 not for magento 2.

There is less information/doc about magento 2. It's being very difficult to customize magento 2.

Can anyone help me how i can do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anyone to help me please!!!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148354/dropdown-for-add-to-cart-qty-in-magento-2  see this

Comment: @AkhileshSoni Thanks for your responde. Can you help me bit more to show dropdown value between max and minimum cart quantity set for product.

Comment: see this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125971/magento-2-how-to-set-a-maximum-order-qty-of-individual-products

Comment: are your problem solved?

Comment: Adding dropdown in place of text box is not adding product in cart. I selected  value form dropdown and click add to cart. it show me empty cart.

Answer (score 0):

According to this file module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml you can try just add to your select id and name from default input

```
<select id="qty" name="qty" class="input-text qty"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the below file in your theme or custom module.

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

After overriding, you need to change the input to select as I do below.

```
<div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <select name="qty" id="qty" class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>">
                    <?php for ($i=1; $i < 50; $i++) :?>
                        <option value="<?= $i?>"><?= $i?></option>
                    <?php endfor;?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

After that clear cache and check. Let me know if you still facing any issues.

Thanks.